# Moving a control with mouse-move in C#

Tags: c#, mousemove

I want to move a button by mouse using C# 
I found this solution on stackoverflow

```
private Point MouseDownLocation;

private void MyControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    }
}

private void MyControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        (button)sender.Left = e.X + (button)sender.Left -MouseDownLocation.X;
        (button)sender.Top = e.Y + (button)sender.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

I hope somebody here can explain to me 
what is difference between 
`e.X`  ( which is the coordinates of mousemoving eventArgs) and `MouseDownLocation.X`

Comment: Rename `MouseDownLocation` to `dragStartLocation`. Better yet, to `_dragStartLocation`. This is just a field, not a event property or anything special

Comment: I believe that this is WinForms, right? Please tag the question correctly.

Comment: okay 
 why do we need to Minus 
- MouseDownLocation.X; 
from the (Left+e.X)
why do we need this ?

Comment: Because when you move the control, you also move the relative position of the mouse.  Not correcting for this has pretty interesting side-effects, try it.